How to optimize searching through json array from file
I'm trying to look through and find the most played songs from my spotify listening history download, and my code below uses 99% cpu for 20 seconds and then fails with "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".
I wanted it to give me the song i most listened to based on total ms listened. I used arraylists and made a class named "Song" with its own constructor to make it easier to contain all the info about a song I want from the json file. The json file structure and my 2 classes are below. I use eclipse 23-09 if it helps. The json file is about 23mb in size and has 23785257 characters.
Main Class:
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();
        Song mostPlayed = null;
        Song mostTimesPlayed = null;
        //ArrayList<Song> highlights = new ArrayList<>();
        long maxLong = 0;
        int maxPlays = 0;
        
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Username\\eclipse-workspace\\csh\\csh\\history.json"));
            Iterator<Object> iterator = jsonArray.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) iterator.next();
                String tempTrack = (String) jsonObject.get("master_metadata_track_name");
                String tempAlbum = (String) jsonObject.get("master_metadata_album_album_name");
                String tempArtist = (String) jsonObject.get("master_metadata_album_artist_name");
                long tempLong = (long) jsonObject.get("ms_played");
                if (songs.isEmpty() /*||  tempLong >=30000*/) {
                    songs.add(new Song(tempTrack, tempAlbum, tempArtist, tempLong));
                }
                else{
                    for (int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
                        if (( songs.get(i)).getTrackName() == tempTrack /*&& tempLong >=30000*/) {
                            (songs.get(i)).updateSong(tempLong);
                        }
                        else {
                            songs.add(new Song(tempTrack, tempAlbum, tempArtist, tempLong));
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
                if ((songs.get(i)).getTotalPlayedFor()> maxLong) {
                    mostPlayed = songs.get(i);
                }
                if ((songs.get(i)).getTotalPlayedFor()> maxPlays) {
                    mostTimesPlayed = songs.get(i);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("――――――――――― Highlights ―――――――――――");
            double maxTimeSec = mostPlayed.getTotalPlayedFor()/1000.0;
            double maxTimeMin = maxTimeSec/60.0;
            double maxTimeHr = maxTimeMin/60.0;
            System.out.println("Most listened to song by time: ");
            System.out.println("Song Name: " + mostPlayed.getTrackName());
            System.out.println("By: " + mostPlayed.getArtist());
            System.out.println("Playtime(ms): " + mostPlayed.getTotalPlayedFor());
            System.out.println("Playtime(s): " + maxTimeSec);
            System.out.println("Playtime(m): " + maxTimeMin);
            System.out.println("Playtime(hr): " + maxTimeHr);
            
        }
        
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
    }

}

Song Class:
public class Song {
    
    private String trackName;
    private String album;
    private String artist;
    private int timesPlayed;
    private long totalPlayedFor;

    /**
     * @return the album
     */
    public String getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }
    public String getTrackName() {
        return trackName;
    }
    public long getTotalPlayedFor() {
        return totalPlayedFor;
    }
    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }
    public int getTimesPlayed() {
        return timesPlayed;
    }
    public Song(String trackName, String album, String artist, long playedFor) {
        this.trackName = trackName;
        this.album = album;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.timesPlayed = 1;
        totalPlayedFor = playedFor;
    }
    public void updateSong(long playedFor) {
        timesPlayed = getTimesPlayed() + 1;
        totalPlayedFor = getTotalPlayedFor() + playedFor;
    }
    
}

Example json object from file:
{
    "ts": "2021-04-21T07:22:32Z",
    "username": "USERNAME",
    "platform": "Windows 10 (10.0.19042; x64)",
    "ms_played": 0,
    "conn_country": "COUNTRYCODE",
    "ip_addr_decrypted": "IPADDRESS",
    "user_agent_decrypted": "unknown",
    "master_metadata_track_name": "Little Dark Age",
    "master_metadata_album_artist_name": "MGMT",
    "master_metadata_album_album_name": "Little Dark Age",
    "spotify_track_uri": "spotify:track:2Y0iGXY6m6immVb2ktbseM",
    "episode_name": null,
    "episode_show_name": null,
    "spotify_episode_uri": null,
    "reason_start": "playbtn",
    "reason_end": "endplay",
    "shuffle": false,
    "skipped": null,
    "offline": false,
    "offline_timestamp": 1618989748702,
    "incognito_mode": false
}

any help would be appreciated!!

is file loaded completely?
And don;t use the ArrayList songs but use Map<String, Song> where key would be trackname.

There is logic problem within the for loop.
for (int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
    if (( songs.get(i)).getTrackName() == tempTrack) {
        (songs.get(i)).updateSong(tempLong);
    }
    else {
        songs.add(new Song(tempTrack, tempAlbum, tempArtist, tempLong));
    }
}

To compare String, use equals().
The for loop will never end.  It is because each time songs.add(), the array size increase immediately.
This should work...
int i;
for (i = songs.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (songs.get(i).getTrackName().equals(tempTrack)) {
        break;
    }
}
if (i >= 0) {
    songs.get(i).updateSong(tempLong);
} else {
    songs.add(new Song(tempTrack, tempAlbum, tempArtist, tempLong));
}


This worked! All I needed to do after was to add if (tempTrack == null)continue; in the main method to prevent podcasts with null as the track name from entering the while loop.
